# Api gives wrong data

Tags: api, google-ads-api

I use the Google AdWords API to collect information about the search volume for a specific keyword. But the data I get as a response doesn't match with the data from the keyword planner or other keyword tools. Here I check the search volume for the keyword "Hunde" in Berlin, Germany in german.

```
targeting_service = adwordsClient.GetService('TargetingIdeaService')
selector = {'ideaType': 'KEYWORD', 'requestType' : 'STATS'}
selector['requestedAttributeTypes'] = ['KEYWORD_TEXT', 'SEARCH_VOLUME', 'TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES']
offset = 0

selector['paging'] = {'startIndex' : str(offset), 'numberResults' : str(1)}
selector['searchParameters'] = [{
   'xsi_type': 'RelatedToQuerySearchParameter',
   'queries': ["hunde"]
}]

selector['searchParameters'].append({
   'xsi_type': 'LocationSearchParameter',
   'locations': [{'id': '1003854'}]
})

selector['searchParameters'].append({
   'xsi_type': 'LanguageSearchParameter',
   'languages': [{'id': '1001'}]
})

page = targeting_service.get(selector)
print(page)
```

As a response I get:

```
{
    'totalNumEntries': 1,
    'entries': [
        {
            'data': [
                {
                    'key': 'KEYWORD_TEXT',
                    'value': {
                        'Attribute.Type': 'StringAttribute',
                        'value': 'hunde'
                    }
                },
                {
                    'key': 'TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES',
                    'value': {
                        'Attribute.Type': 'MonthlySearchVolumeAttribute',
                        'value': [
                            {
                                'year': 2020,
                                'month': 12,
                                'count': 4743382
                            },
                            {
                                'year': 2020,
                                'month': 11,
                                'count': 455583
                            },
                            {
                                'year': 2020,
                                'month': 10,
                                'count': 8797951
                            },
                            {
                                'year': 2020,
                                'month': 9,
                                'count': 5218694
                            },
                            {
                                'year': 2020,
                                'month': 8,
                                'count': 5089585
                            },
                            {
                                'year': 2020,
                                'month': 7,
                                'count': 3149591
                            },
                            {
                                'year': 2020,
                                'month': 6,
                                'count': 3020638
                            },
                            {
                                'year': 2020,
                                'month': 5,
                                'count': 4928527
                            },
                            {
                                'year': 2020,
                                'month': 4,
                                'count': 754959
                            },
                            {
                                'year': 2020,
                                'month': 3,
                                'count': 5649676
                            },
                            {
                                'year': 2020,
                                'month': 2,
                                'count': 1590789
                            },
                            {
                                'year': 2020,
                                'month': 1,
                                'count': 2506674
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    'key': 'SEARCH_VOLUME',
                    'value': {
                        'Attribute.Type': 'LongAttribute',
                        'value': 3825504
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But this data doesn't match with the data from the keyword planer.
Avg. monthly searches (Keyword planner): 10K – 100K

Does somebody knows why the data I'm receiving is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

These questions pop up somewhat frequently and are generally not easy to answer. Did you make sure that the specified [`searchParameters` in your request correspond exactly to what you are using in the Keyword Planner](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/targeting-idea-service#mapping_to_keyword_planner)?

Additionally, you could check out the [`KeywordPlanService`](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/keyword-planning/generate-historical-metrics) of the newer Ads API. According to this [post](https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/9SVa0ncoR9M/m/IvHBoXzNCwAJ) by a Google Ads API advisor, it should be closer to what you can do in the web UI than the Adwords API's `TargetingIdeaService`.

Answer (score 0):

If OP didn't figure it out, i've had the same headaches.
I solved this when adding NetworkSearchParameter to [searchparameter] so the API only returns google data.
my code after adding in the additional argument.

```
    selector['searchParameters'] = [{
    'xsi_type' : 'RelatedToQuerySearchParameter',
    'queries' : sublist,
     },
     {
     'xsi_type':'LocationSearchParameter',
     'locations' : [country_ids[country]],
      },
      {
      'xsi_type': 'NetworkSearchParameter',
      'networkSetting': {
                    'targetGoogleSearch': True,
                    'targetSearchNetwork': False,
                    'targetContentNetwork': False,
                    'targetPartnerSearchNetwork': False
      }}]
```